# Zapier - add data to JSON response (App development)

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

We are creating a Zapier app to expose our APIs to the public, so anyone can use it.  The main endpoint that people are using returns a very large and complex JSON object.  Zapier, it looks like, has a really difficult time parsing nested complex JSON.  But it does wonderful with a very simple response object such as

{ "field": "value" }

Our data that is being returned has this structure and we want to move some of the fields to the root of the response so it's easily parsed by Zapier.

```
"networkSections": [
    {
        "identifier": "Deductible",
        "label": "Deductible",
        "inNetworkParameters": [
            {
                "key": "Annual",
                "value": " 600.00",
                "message": null,
                "otherInfo": null
            },
            {
                "key": "Remaining",
                "value": " 600.00",
                "message": null,
                "otherInfo": null
            }
        ],
        "outNetworkParameters": null
    },
```

So, can we do something to return for example the remaining deductible?

I got this far (adding outputFields) but this returns an array of values.  I'm not sure how to parse through this array either in the Zap or in the App.

```
 {key: 'networkSections[]inNetworkParameters[]key', label: 'xNetworkSectionsKey',type: 'string'},
```

ie this returns an array of "Annual", "Remaining", etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. In this case, there's a lot going on, and `outputFields` can't quite handle it all. :(

In your example, `inNetworkParameters` contains an array of objects. Throughout our documentation, we refer to these as [line items](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/action-fields/#parent-key). These lines items can be passed to other actions, but the different expected structures presents a bit of a problem. The way we've handled this is by letting users map line-items from one step's output to another step's input per field. So if step 1 returns

```
{
  "some_array": [
    {
      "some_key": "some_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the next step needs to send

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "some_other_key": "some_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

users can accomplish that by mapping `some_array.some_key` to `data.some_other_key`.

All of that being said, if you want to always return a `Remaining Deductible` object, you'll have to do it by modifying the result object itself. As long as this data is always in that same order, you can do something akin to

```
var data = z.JSON.parse(bundle.response.content);
data["Remaining Deductible"] = data.networkSections[0].inNetworkParameters[1].value;
return data;
```

If the order differs, you'll have to implement some sort of search to find the objects you'd like to return.

I hope that all helps!

Comment: Thanks Caleb but JSON order is not guaranteed right?   Is there an example of doing an if/then/else?  I'm not even sure what language your app code is in.  TYVM

Comment: I was using JavaScript. :) Objects in JSON do not have a guaranteed order, but arrays should maintain their order (see https://json.org/'s definitions of both structures).

Answer (score 1):

Caleb got me where I wanted to go.  For completeness this is the solution.

In the creates directory I have a js file for the actual call.  The perform part is below.

```
perform: (z, bundle) => {
  const promise = z.request({
    url: 'https://api.example.com/API/Example/' + bundle.inputData.elgRequestID,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    }
  });
  return promise.then(function(result) {
     var data = JSON.parse(result.content);
     for (var i=0; i<data.networkSections.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<data.networkSections[i].inNetworkParameters.length; j++) {
           // DEDUCT
           if (data.networkSections[i].identifier == "Deductible" &&
                           data.networkSections[i].inNetworkParameters[j].key == "Annual")
             data["zAnnual Deductible"] = data.networkSections[i].inNetworkParameters[j].value;

        } // inner for

     } // outer for
     return data;
     });
```